# Why doesn't Broadcast Receiver trigger continously?

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcast Receiver which displays  a toast if **GPS** is put on or off. I just want to know why doesn't  toast get displayed continuously as long as the **GPS**  keep on.
please find below the code i used.

```
 public class gpsbroad extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     if (enabled==true) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "gps on",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, LocalService.class);
            //context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
     else
     {
         Toast.makeText(context, "gps off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
     }

     if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "in android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, LocalService.class);
            //context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
}
```

Comment: The clue is in the 'changed' part of PROVIDERS_CHANGED. That's the intent that is broadcast when there is a change of state.

Answer (score 0):

A `BroadcastReceiver` "wakes up" when there is an `Intent` it is interested in receiving. It will execute the code in `onReceive()` and that's it. In fact, beyond that point it may as well be destroyed as far as the system is concerned.

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.

A `Toast` can only show for a limited duration, either `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. In fact, those are the only durations you can specify.

Put the two together and the result is you'll see a brief message pop up on screen when you get the intent your want. In short there is nothing about your code that would make a Toast (or anything for that matter) remain on screen for as long as GPS is on. I suggest you look into `NotificationManager`, but I really don't see the point -- the phone will display a GPS icon in the system status bar anyway.

Comment: I want to start a BroadCast receiver after every 3 minutes. how can i do that?

Comment: AlarmManager. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html